# How to get name of a RavenDB document

Tags: database, linq, ravendb

My code is:

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession(databaseName))
{
    var list = session.Query<dynamic>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName").ToArray();

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

But it does not give me the name of the document. I want to list all of the documents in single database.

Comment: What are you trying to do, why do you want to list all the docs in the database?

Comment: If you just want to see all the docs, spin up the ravendb server and visit http://localhost:8080/docs or http://localhost:8080/raven/documents.html

Comment: Hello Matt , I am building GUI for Ravendb and it is one of my operation to retrieve all the documents in single database. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, it's a bit more generic and it allows access to the raw documents

```
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    //Issue a dummy query to make sure the indexing has finished
    var dummyQuery = session.Query<dynamic>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName")
        .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
        .ToList();

    //First get all the document types, i.e. the different entity names
    var docTypes = store.DatabaseCommands.GetTerms("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName", "Tag", "", 128);
    foreach (var type in docTypes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n{0}:", type);
        //Might need to do paging here, can only get at most 1024 docs in 1 go!
        var docs = store.DatabaseCommands.StartsWith(type, 0, 1024).ToList();

    foreach (var doc in docs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}: {1}", doc.Key, doc.ToJson());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. It really works. It is working for Default database. I have modified your code for specified database and posting it.:)

Comment: What is the use of the string "tag" in store.DatabaseCommands.GetTerms() ?

Comment: It's the name of the field you want to get the terms for, the one that `Raven/DocumentsByEntityName` uses, see https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Database/Plugins/Builtins/CreateSilverlightIndexes.cs#L17

Comment: Also if this answer worked for you, can you click the tick by the side of it?

Answer (score 0):

modifying Matt waren's code for specified database.

```
 public void DocumentNamesWithMetadata(string databaseName="1")
        {
            using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession(databaseName))
            {
                //Issue a dummy query to make sure the indexing has finished 
                var dummyQuery = session.Query<dynamic>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName")
                                        .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
                                        .ToList();

                //First get all the document types, i.e. the different entity names 
                var docTypes = session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.GetTerms("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName", "Tag", "", 128);
                foreach (var type in docTypes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n{0}:", type);
                    //Might need to do paging here, can only get at most 1024 docs in 1 go! 
                    var docs = session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.StartsWith(type, 0, 1024).ToList();

                    foreach (var doc in docs)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("    {0}: {1}", doc.Key, doc.ToJson());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```